# Is there any extension in Visual Studio Code , which is similar to Tramp Mode in Emacs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) (Transparent Remote Access, Multiple Protocols) is a package for editing remote files, similar to AngeFtp or efs. Whereas the others use FTP to connect to the remote host and to transfer the files, TRAMP uses a remote shell connection (rlogin, telnet, ssh). It can transfer the files using rcp or a similar program, or it can encode the file contents (using uuencode or base64) and transfer them right through the shell connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FUSE for a somewhat similar effect. It's not editor specific, but mounts remote file systems via SSH, FTP and whatnot directly to your local file system so you can use it with *any* Editor.

You didn't mention on what operating system you, but here's the link to the version for macOS: https://osxfuse.github.io

Comment: The crucial difference is that TRAMP transparently runs shell commands on the remote system, not locally. This is what I want from TRAMP.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like as of now there is at least one similar package to Tramp mode for VSCode.  I couldn't directly find in the documentation how you would open a remote shell inside VSCode, but it seems like it would have to be possible given the rest of the plugin.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
- https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks

I have a terminal menu in VSCode that I can open up and directly ssh to stuff, so that seems to cover both sides of the "Tramp" mode usage

Comment: The Remote-SSH extension is great - when you have a fully-fledged PC on the other side. It provides impressive access to filesystem and shell of a remote system, even on a laggy connection.
Unfortunately it's not feasible for one common use-case: working with small embedded systems. I often find that I need to edit config files on remote systems on systems where I can't install anything. For that TRAMP-mode is unbeatable. (It even works on systems where the entire filesystem is read-only.)